# SQLite Running sum of transactions over products calculated daily

Tags: sqlite, join, window-functions, recursive-query

I have a table (pantry) used as a ledger, where the addition and removal of produce are logged over time, only when a transactions occur. I would like to get the running sum of all products ever logged, on a daily basis. There might be a better way to get this result but I don't want to pivot the table.

The result I am trying to get is the one in the tables here. Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `CROSS` join a recursive `CTE` to the distinct products of the table and then a LEFT join to the table to get the running sum with `SUM()` window function:

```
with dates as (
  select min(date) date from pantry
  union all
  select date(date, '+1 day')
  from dates
  where date < (select max(date) from pantry)
)
select *
from (
  select d.date, p.produce,
        sum(t.transactions) over (partition by p.produce order by d.date) running_sum
  from dates d 
  cross join (select distinct produce from pantry) p
  left join pantry t on t.date = d.date and t.produce = p.produce
)
where running_sum is not null
order by date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0b125ef2be5e42d821edf1d7ee28e6e3).
Results:

```
> date       | produce | running_sum
> :--------- | :------ | ----------:
> 2020-01-01 | banana  |          50
> 2020-01-02 | banana  |          50
> 2020-01-03 | apple   |           5
> 2020-01-03 | banana  |          40
> 2020-01-04 | apple   |           5
> 2020-01-04 | banana  |          40
> 2020-01-05 | apple   |           5
> 2020-01-05 | banana  |          40
> 2020-01-06 | apple   |           5
> 2020-01-06 | banana  |          40
> 2020-01-07 | apple   |           3
> 2020-01-07 | banana  |          20
> 2020-01-07 | grapes  |         100
> 2020-01-08 | apple   |           3
> 2020-01-08 | banana  |          20
> 2020-01-08 | grapes  |         100
> 2020-01-09 | apple   |           3
> 2020-01-09 | banana  |          20
> 2020-01-09 | grapes  |          50
> 2020-01-10 | apple   |           3
> 2020-01-10 | banana  |          20
> 2020-01-10 | grapes  |          50
> 2020-01-11 | apple   |          -1
> 2020-01-11 | banana  |          20
> 2020-01-11 | grapes  |          50
> 2020-01-11 | melon   |           2
```